# vuex store losing data on PAGE REGRESH

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am building authentication system in laravel and vuejs, I am building using JWT and storing token in lacalstorage. I am able to store user data in vuex store and yes i can see under vuex area in devtool. The problem is when i am refreshing page i am losing it . I wanna persist user's information, It should not get deleted on a page refresh . How can i achieve that

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import userStore from './components/user/userStore'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'


export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules : {
        userStore
    },
    strict : debug
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to save your Vuex to localstorage or cookie.

There is a plugin to help save your state to localstorage https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: thanx , but i have got my token inside localstorage even after page refresh but not losing from vuex store

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your issue?

Comment: i have jwt token in localstorage for that user, It's there in local storage... only i am losing vuex's store part i.e userStore in code after refresh , after refresh userStore shows null...

Comment: So you can save your userStore to localstorage too!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this plugin

https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist

> A Typescript-ready Vuex plugin that enables you to save the state of your app to a persisted storage like Cookies or localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it that way:

```
state: {
    authenticated: localStorage.getItem('yourToken')
}
```

Now you can set your `this.authenticated` in `actions: {}` or wherever else to true or false.
The meaning is that you have to store your `localStrage` by default to your i.e. `autenticated`.
If you cant follow, just let me know and I could give you more example of my case. Maybe you'll figured it out that way.

### EDIT:

Use `sessionStorage` to store.